# Not able to access firebase from a react-native iOS application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-ios

I am trying to access the firebase database from a react-native application. I have setup a web-app project in the Firebase console.
The client setup done in the app is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header } from './components/common';
import  LoginForm  from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component{
componentWillMount(){
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyC9UxLHlEn2cRTOQGR6nnDBMIveMjNfntk',
        authDomain: 'authentication-5782a.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://authentication-5782a.firebaseio.com',
        projectId: 'authentication-5782a',
        storageBucket: 'authentication-5782a.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '471244308758'
      });   
}

    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header headerText="Authentication"/>
                    <LoginForm />

            </View>


        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

After adding all the required things I am still not able to add any entry to the database or fetch any. What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you check your Database Rules on the Firebase Console?

Comment: Yeah they are set to public.

Comment: Please add the code where you interact with Firebase and any error messages you're seeing.